# On change of select, find next div and hide

Tags: jquery, html

When a change occurs in select_type I would like to hide the next .div_condition.  The div (a_condition) is dynamically injected into the page, so there could be many of them, so it needs to find the next .div_condition  in the container (a_condition).

The html...

```
<div class="a_condition">                                 
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="badge i_condition">1</span>
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" >If</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select class="form-control select_type">
                <option value="0">Select...</option>
                <option value="intent|.topScoringIntent.intent=product">intent=product</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group div_condition">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" >Condition</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select class="form-control select_condition">
                <option value="0">Select...</option>
                <option value="Is">Is</option>
                <option value="Is Not">Is Not</option>
                <option value="Contains">Contains</option>
                <option value="Begins With">Begins With</option>
                <option value="Ends With">Ends With</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have tried this; but just can't seem to find/hide it...

```
$(document).on('change', ".select_type", function (e) {
    //hide or show based on selected type
    var arr = this.value.split("|");
    switch (arr[0]) {
        case "intent": 
            var $elem = $(this).nextAll(".div_condition").hide();
            console.log($elem)
                //.closest(".div_condition").hide();
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: why `switch` statement for only one condition?

Comment: there will be many conditions

Comment: I think $(this) => select component, so, when you call $(this).nextAll(".div_condition"), it will find inner select component instead find from parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are bounding each pair of `<select>`s by `div.a_condition`, the following should work:

```
$(document).on('change', ".select_type", function (e) {
    //hide or show based on selected type
    var arr = this.value.split("|");
    switch (arr[0]) {
        case "intent": 
            $(this).parents('.a_condition').find('.div_condition').hide();
            break;
    }
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jmgfn0n/)